# Is there a way to access model parameters by name in a Pytorch loss function?

Tags: pytorch

I'm trying to write a Pytorch loss function that measures the weight similarity of two models with similar but somewhat different structures - namely, Model 1 has extra layers that Model 2 doesn't have that are "collapsed" upon prediction (more specifically, Model 1 uses layers injected by [loralib](https://github.com/microsoft/LoRA/tree/main))

I'm aware that you can typically iterate over the model's parameters e.g. to construct something like this:

```
class WeightSimilarityLoss(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, target_model):
    super(WeightSimilarityLoss, self).__init__()
    self.target_model = target_model

  def forward(self, current_model):
    current_weights = current_model.parameters()
    target_weights = self.target_model.parameters()
    loss = 0
    for cw, tw in zip(current_weights, target_weights):
        loss += torch.norm(cw - tw)
    return 1/(loss + 1)
```

However this approach necessarily requires iterating over all of the parameters - in my use case, this would mean that Model 1 and 2 would have to have exactly the same structure.

What I'd instead like to do is something like this:

```
def get_parameter_dict(model):
  parameter_dict = {}
  for name, param in model.named_parameters():
    parameter_dict[name] = param
  return parameter_dict

class Loss(nn.Module):
  ...

  def forward(self, model):
    model_weights = get_parameter_dict(model)
    layer1_weight = model_weights['layer1.weight'] + (model_weights['layer1.lora_B'] @ model_weights['layer1.lora_A'])
    # proceed to do loss function calculations
```

Is such a structure possible - i.e. one that directly references the parameter name in the loss function? If so, how can it be done? If not, are there any other ways to perform the operation I'm describing here?

**EDIT:** A very simplified version of what I'm trying to do is as follows:

```
import loralib as lora

class LoRANet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(LoRANet, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = lora.Linear(2, 2, r=1)

    def forward(self, x):
        return x

lora_net = LoRANet()
lora.mark_only_lora_as_trainable(lora_net)

def get_parameter_dict(model):
    return dict(model.named_parameters())

class DummyWeightLoss(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self):
        super(DummyWeightLoss, self).__init__()

  def forward(self, model):
    model_weights = get_parameter_dict(model)
    return 1/(torch.norm(model_weights['fc1.lora_B']) + 1)

optimizer = optim.Adam(lora_net.parameters(), lr=0.01)
loss_primary = DummyWeightLoss()
lora_net.train()
for epoch in range(10):
  optimizer.zero_grad()
  loss = loss_primary(lora_net)
  loss.backward()
  optimizer.step()
```

In this case, the fc1.lora_B parameter does not change at all despite the fact that it should theoretically grow to have as large of a norm as possible (then the loss will tend to 0). Printing the model weights at each step (i.e. adding a `print(model_weights)` call in the forward function of the DummyWeightLoss) just constantly shows this:

```
{'fc1.weight': Parameter containing:
tensor([[-0.4972,  0.2462],
        [ 0.1281,  0.2452]]), 'fc1.bias': Parameter containing:
tensor([-0.2513, -0.4095]), 'fc1.lora_A': Parameter containing:
tensor([[ 0.7022, -0.2204]], requires_grad=True), 'fc1.lora_B': Parameter containing:
tensor([[0.],
        [0.]], requires_grad=True)}
```

**EDIT 2:** Further experimentation shows that this is likely a use-case specific issue. The current answer to this question appears to work in the general case. As such I'm accepting the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure.

You don't really need both models to have the same structure, you can just iterate over each of them separately.

Following your idea, you can always create a dictionary that will map parameters' names to their weight tensors, like this, which is equivalent to your implementation

```
def get_parameter_dict(model):
  return dict(model.named_parameters())
```

Then,

```
class WeightSimilarityLoss(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, target_model):
    super(WeightSimilarityLoss, self).__init__()
    self.target_model = target_model
    self.target_model_weights = self.get_parameter_dict(self.target_model)
  
  def get_parameter_dict(model):
    return dict(model.named_parameters()) 
  
  def forward(self, current_model):
    current_weights = self.get_parameter_dict(current_model)
    target_weights = self.target_model_weights
    loss = 0
    # calculate whatever loss you need
```

Provided I understood your question correctly, this should about cover it.

Comment: Perhaps I'm implementing something incorrectly, but setting even a simple loss w/ a forward method like

def forward(self, current_model):
    parameters = get_parameter_dict(model)
    return 1/(torch.norm(parameters['fc1.lora_A]) + 1)

doesn't change fc1.lora_A when trained even with the parameter dict method you described. Should your method make this work correctly?

Comment: I think it should. I'll add an example later. In the meantime, can you edit the question and share more of your code? Particularly the code that does backprop